# Why am I getting an error message from Android NDK r11 while my project is built using Android NDK r16?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, libc, libc++

I have an Android project with a third party library (`.so`). Along with the third party `.so` file, I'm also providing the `libc++_shared.so` library that is needed along with the third party library.

After building the Android project and running it on an Android device (Android 6.x), I get this `abort` message:

`[INFO]  libc: /Volumes/Android/buildbot/out_dirs/aosp-ndk-r11-release/build/tmp/build-72234/build-libc++/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/../llvm-libc++abi/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:74: void abort_message(const char *, ...): assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type`

The problem here is that I don't have the **Android NDK r11** configured within my system (`MacOS`). I downloaded and configured the **Android NDK r16**. I also can see during the build the **configured** NDK is used (path of my configured `ANDROID_NDK` within my `.bash_profile`).

This `llvm-libc++` of `r11` is not compatible with the third party `.so` library. Why am I getting the abort message from the **NDK r11**?

Comment: Which NDK is your 3rd party `.so` built with?

Comment: The third party `.so` is built with NDK r14

Comment: Let's ask a different question: is `/Volumes/Android/buildbot/` a valid path on your Mac? Probably, it isn't. In which case the message is triggered by some library you are using. You can **grep** the prebuilt libraries for this message to pin the troublemaker.

Comment: Hi Alex, It isn't a valid path on my Mac, indeed. And it isn't also a valid one on the Android device. How could it (`abort_message`) then called/triggered? And besides that I'm also providing the `libc++_shared.so` file along and see it's packaged within the APK. Is there a way to tell the system to only use the provided one? But I'll look into the provided libraries to start with to identify any matching messages..

Comment: Guys, I posted the answer on my question. Thanks for the effort and provided info that helped me finding the answer!

Comment: FYI, `/Volumes/Android/buildbot/` is the path the NDK itself was built at on the Android buildbots.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question. It seems that the Mobile Application Development Platform (Appcelerator Titanium) I'm using was injecting its own `libc++_shared.so` file during the app build phase. This is why my own `libc++_shared.so` file didn't get in the `APK` file. It was another file all along. And that file was from the **Android NDK r11**.

The file that is copied during the build phase is located within the Titanium SDK: `sdk/android/native/libs/*/libc++_shared.so`.

Comment: This sounds like a *very bad SDK design*. You can force the latest version of `libc++_shared.so` to be packaged, but who can guarantee that Titanium will work with it correctly? You can probably build Titanium from [sources](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android), but even then I recommend to [switch](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/android/runtime/v8/Application.mk#L12) to static STL.